# Is paper_trail recommended for use with rails_admin in production?

Tags: rails-admin, paper-trail-gem

I'm revisiting `paper_trail` after a while, and the documentation seems to indicate that it is not recommended for use with `rails_admin` in production. Is this correct?

Comment: It would help considerably if you included a link to the documentation to which you're referring.

Comment: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#4b-associations "4.b. Associations
Experimental feature with many known issues. Not recommended for production."

Comment: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#1b-installation "If using rails_admin, you must enable the experimental Associations feature."

Comment: Please [edit] your question to put the details there, where they can be seen. Burying it in comment clutter doesn't help much. :-) Not sure what your question is, though; ***Experimental feature** with **many known issues. Not recommended for production.*** seems pretty clear and specific, and the **Not recommended for production.** seems to very specifically answer the question you've asked in the title of your post with a very loud **NO, it's not recommended for production use**...

Comment: @KenWhite is right, is just that feature. We've been using the gem on production quite succesfully for many years now. Yes the versions table grows quite fast quite large, but you can easily trim it if you don't need the whole history.

Comment: Thank you. I was just surprised that ```rails_admin``` is apparently dead now and wanted to connect the dots and make sure. Sad.